# Why every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ linearly independent generalized eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ linearly independent generalized eigenvalues?

I don't understand the theorem, Can somebody help me prove it?

Comment: This is only true when the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is completely reducible, so it might be better to say "every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over an algebraically closed field". Then what it comes down to is basically a proof that every such a matrix has a Jordan Canonical Form...the proof contains a few parts - maybe someone can summarize it here, but i would suggest since there are many (online) resources regarding this that you look at different proofs, search the web for JCF, etc. to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Search "Down with determinants".